# Mapster маппинг на поле с объектом с несколькими конструкторами без дефолтного

Tags: c#, .net

Разбираюсь с `Mappster` - есть такие классы:

```
class In
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string C;
}

class Out
{
    public Sub Sub;
    public string C;
}

class Sub
{
    public string A; 
    public string B;
    
    public Sub(string a, string b)
        =>(A,B) = (a,b);
}
```

Задаю правила:

```
var mapper = new Mapper();

mapper.Config
    .ForType<In, Out>()
    .Map(@out=> @out.Sub, @in => new Sub(@in.A, @in.B));
```

Если замапить сейчас все нормально, но если добавить в класс `Sub` еще один конструктор (допустим `public Sub(string a)=> A=a;`) Маппинг отвалится с ошибкой

```
Error while compiling
source=UserQuery+In
destination=UserQuery+Out
type=Map

Error while compiling
source=UserQuery+Sub
destination=UserQuery+Sub
type=Map
No default constructor for type 'Sub', please use 'ConstructUsing' or 'MapWith'
```

Почитал документацию, попробовал так сяк и 'ConstructUsing' и 'MapWith' - не подошли (или, что вероятнее, я что-то не так делаю).

Comment: Никогда не понимал смысла всяких ООП. Любая парадигма должна упрощать написание кода. А вот ООП его только усложняют. Код, написанный процедурно, будет проще, нагляднее, понятнее хоть профи, хоть новичку и работать быстрее. И не надо создавать тысячную тему на форуме...

Comment: Круто. Я разве спрашивал что мне использовать, а что нет?

Comment: Парламент не место для дисскуссий))

Comment: Я к тому, что если у вас нет ответа - то и не надо писать. А то в рунете почему-то популярен шаблон - спрашиваешь как помыть пол шваброй, а тебе начинают советовать моющие пылесосы или вовсе отказаться от пола в сторону землянки. Так как мне помыть пол шваброй?

Comment: Так как мне помыть пол шваброй? - Берёшь швабру и моешь.

Comment: Мсье, не умеет в метафоры? =)

Comment: public Sub(string a, string b="")
        =>(A,B) = (a,b); попробуйте вместо нового конструктора

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел, достаточно в конфиге добавить такое

```
config.ForType<Sub, Sub>().MapToConstructor(true);
```

Тогда сработает даже мой специфический кейс:

```
void Main()
{
    var mapper = new Mapper();
    
    var config = mapper.Config;

    config
        .ForType<In, Out>()
        .Map(@out => @out.Sub, @in => new Sub(@in.A, @in.B))
        .Map(@out => @out.Sub2, @in => new Sub(@in.A2, @in.B2));
        
    config.ForType<Sub, Sub>().MapToConstructor(true);
    
    var @in = new In
    {
        A = "A1",
        A2 = "A2",
        B = "B1",
        B2 = "B2",
        C ="Cfff"
    };
    
    @in.Dump();
        
    var @out = mapper.Map<Out>(@in);
    
    @out.Dump();
}

class In
{
    public string A;
    public string B;
    public string A2;
    public string B2;
    public string C;
}

class Out
{
    public Sub Sub;
    public Sub Sub2;

    public string C;
}

class Sub
{
    public string A;
    public string B;

    public Sub(string a, string b)
        => (A, B) = (a, b);

    public Sub(string a)
        => (A, B) = (a, null);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
using MapsterMapper;

static class MapperExtensions
{
    public static Out Map(this IMapper mapper, In @in)
    {
        return new Out
        {
            Sub = new Sub(@in.A, @in.B),
            C = @in.C
        };
    }
}
```

Проверяем:

```
In i = new In { A = "a", B = "b", C = "c" };

IMapper mapper = new Mapper();

Out o = mapper.Map(i);

Console.WriteLine(o.Sub.A + " " + o.Sub.B + " " + o.C);
```

---

Я всегда считал и продолжаю считать, что любая утилита/библиотека должна упрощать написание кода. Автоматические мапперы можно применять, но только до тех пор, пока они делают свою работу автоматически. Как только приходится описывать маппинг вручную в конфиге маппера, то лучше от него отказаться.

В показанном мной примере ручной маппинг элементарен. В то время как конфиг с описанием правил для маппера в несколько раз больше. Так зачем писать больше?

[The reasons behind why I don't use AutoMapper](https://cezarypiatek.github.io/post/why-i-dont-use-automapper/) - замечательная статья (и вообще блог хороший), рекомендую к прочтению. В комментариях ссылка на ответ автора этого АвтоМаппера, где он юлит, но в итоге признаёт, что чаще всего нет смысла использовать его детище.

Comment: Ахаха! Класс. оч смешно. Но мне больше интересно как сделать это средствами собственно самого мапстера.

Comment: @srvr4vr - вы хотели готовое решение, как на английском форуме. Вот оно!

Comment: Александр, ваше ерничество, конечно, забавное, но несколько токсичное. Пойдите выпейте уже кофе, отдохните. Порою помогает. Мне не готовое решение надо, у меня в руках инструмент который вкатил мой лид, и желание понять как им пользоваться в данном конкретном случае, а потом уже решить нужен ли такой инструмент вообще. Вручную ясен пень можно все перекрутить - у нас сейчас так и все и работает. Я кстати создал Issue на гитхабе мапстера - это либо баг, либо там покажут как это у них по идее должно работать.

Comment: @srvr4vr - я не ёрничаю, я искренне стараюсь помочь. И искренне считаю применение мапперов в большинстве случаев (не во всех!) лишним и создающим больше проблем, чем их решающим.

Comment: Я возможно даже с вами соглашусь. Но у меня уже больше спортивный интерес.